# view the code behind of a list in HTML

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Can anyone please help me understand how can I view the code behind a list created in share point. I am trying to open the aspx page of the list and code behind the list is in xml.I want to view the list in HTML.

Comment: what exactly do you search?